# Repeat over files in a File > Open dialog with Applescript

Tags: dialog, applescript, finder

In the below script I use an Application other than Finder to launch an "Open" browser and perform a search in it.

I've got the window into the state I want, but whatever I try can't access the list of files to repeat over.

If anyone can help by adding the code to repeat over that file list and log out the file path of each file it'd be a huge help.

Thanks a lot.

[image: preview with an "open file" dialog active, with a search performed]

```
tell application "Preview"

  -- start the app
  activate

  -- let it boot up
  delay 3

  -- ensure it still has focus
  activate

end tell

tell application "System Events"

  tell process "Preview"

    -- spawn "Open" window
    keystroke "o" using {command down}
    delay 0.5

    -- spawn "Go to" window
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 0.5

    -- expand scope of search to all of this mac
    keystroke "/"
    keystroke return
    delay 0.5

    -- spawn search field
    keystroke "f" using {command down}
    delay 0.5

    -- perform search
    keystroke ".jpg OR .jpeg"
    keystroke return

  end tell

end tell
```

Comment: Am I missing something here or are you asking the same question again but wording it different?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305981/applescript-get-absolute-path-of-item-in-a-file-open-window

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `mdfind` or `choose file` instead?

```
mdfind kMDItemContentType=public.jpeg -onlyin /
```

```
osascript -e 'tell app "SystemUIServer"
choose file default location "/" with multiple selections allowed
end' &
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events"
keystroke "f" using command down
keystroke "kind:JPEG image"
keystroke tab & tab & tab & tab & tab & tab
delay 1
key code 125
delay 0.1
keystroke "a" using command down
keystroke return
end'
```

Comment: Hey Lauri, if I've read your answer correctly I think you're launching Finder, performing a search then doing a Select All, is that right? What I'm looking for is to open eg Preview.app's File > Open dialog then iterate over the files displayed in that window. I want to inspect each item individually as I will want to open some of them but not others.